# How can I delete LittleBigPlanet without losing my save data?

Tags: little-big-planet

I downloaded LittleBigPlanet almost a year ago when it was free and recently, I got the Game of the Year edition. I was hoping to just delete the game from my system and just use the Game of the Year edition from now on, but I noticed that the save data wasn't in the Save Data Utility. I believe that all of the save data is in the game itself on the console and if I delete it, I will lose all of that save data.

Is there a way to get the save data from the downloaded game into the Save Data Utility so that way I can delete the game and still have the save data? If not, then will I have to live with the dowloaded version forever for the sake of keeping the saved game?

Comment: for LBP any save should be in the "Saved Data Utility (PS3<sup>tm</sup>)" (right above the trophy collection), for LBP2 it's in the "Game Data utility"

Comment: There should be an option in game to export the save (the game used to have a bug where saves got too big and made the game unplayable, that's why they stopped using the save for game data)

Comment: @JohnoBoy Will the profile backup retain all of my game data? So if I delete LBP from my console, all of the data will be in the profile backup?

Comment: If you log-in with the proper PSN Account, yes, exactly!

Answer (score 1):

Saved data for all *LBP* games (**LittleBigPlanet**, LittleBigPlanet 2, LittleBigPlanet Karting, LittleBigPlanet Prehistoric Moves and LittleBigPlanet 3) is stored in the *"Game Data Utility"*, this means that deleting the game will still keep the save file. **Don't worry!**